# How to add padding in between cards in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a row consisting of 8 cards.
I want to have all these in single line.
There is a margin of column size 2 on left side and I have set each card of size 1 (so 8 + 2 = 10)
But then, my row is all messed up.
[image]

Currently my code for border is

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="card-header"> Discover new genres {{genre}}</div>
</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 text-center">
    <div class="card border-secondary mb-3" style="width: 10rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top img-responsive full-width circle-img rounded-circle" src="{{rec['artpath']}}" alt="{{rec['name']}}"> 
</img>
   <div class="card-block">
    <div class="card-body"><p class="card-title text-center "><small>{{rec["name"]}}</small></p></div>
   </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

I want the card to have this width (so not card to be small)..It can overflow on the right side of the screen..
How do i do this?

Comment: Does this sit inside a `container` or a `container-fluid`?

Comment: @snack_overflow container-fluid

Comment: I'd recommend creating a [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) with your CSS included, then we can try and fix this problem for you. Without seeing whats around this block of code it's difficult for us to replicate this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has to do with your inline style of `width:10rem`.  It's going to supersede the width of `col-lg-1` when it is greater than that column width.  Removing this inline style results in expected behavior.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card-header"> Discover new genres {{genre}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <div class="card border-secondary mb-3" style="">
        <img class="card-img-top img-responsive full-width circle-img rounded-circle" src="{{rec['artpath']}}" alt="{{rec['name']}}"> 
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-title text-center">
              <small>{{rec["name"]}}</small>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <div class="card border-secondary mb-3" style="">
        <img class="card-img-top img-responsive full-width circle-img rounded-circle" src="{{rec['artpath']}}" alt="{{rec['name']}}"> 
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-title text-center">
              <small>{{rec["name"]}}</small>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
  </div>
</div>
```

For the purposes of this example I've changed your column breakpoints to something that works better when you choose 'Run Code Snippet'.  I suspect you were applying an inline width because `col-lg-1` is too small; that being the case I recommend you consider a larger column breakpoint in lieu of inline styles overriding grid behavior.